# Multiple User-Controls on one Form

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls

I recently started a little project which is about a custom button as a User-Control. I know, I could have just made a library but back to my problem.
The custom User-Control button is finished and I realized that when ever I change any custom property it changes for all buttons (I pulled the User-Control from the ToolBox onto the form multiple times). Where is my mistake?

I really don't wanna post any part of this trash code here but if you really want me to do so, just tell me!

Lastly I have a little screenshot for you:

[The Form how it is currently looking. Just to give you an idea of what I am talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhHOb.png)

Hopefully you guys can help me out and thank you in advance ^^

How my custom Properties are made: @Chase Rocker (here you go :D)

```
    Public Shared customFont As Font = New Font("MS Reference Sans Serif", 10)
Public Property TextFont() As Font
    Get
        Return customFont
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Font)
        customFont = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Doesn't each instance of the control has an individual name? Each should have it's own properties and state.

Comment: Post some of your custom control's code which handles those properties.

Comment: **[Shared (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shared)**.  Also please read [ask] and take the [tour].  `I really don't wanna post any part of this code here` thats so not how the site works

Comment: Not the friendliest answer I've ever read but at least it helped me out, so I guess I have to say thank you!

Comment: Yeah. No offence intended, but sometimes people here (including myself occasionally) get a bit frustrated when a question can often be solved by a little googling or understanding of the code. :-) As it happens the code you posted included the problem line. A shared object is the same object shared between all instances of the class that it is contained in. You should be able to get away with removing the `Shared` keyword. Don't let our occasionally surly attitude put you off this site. It is a great site - really!

Comment: Yeah I know it was a pretty bad question... Well at least I could learn something and try out how to post questions.